# Change dictionary values from $ to float value. Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary

I have scraped 3 different websites and obtained 3 different values with corresponding keys.
I want to divide these values by 2 before I pass them through Venmo to make a request. However, I have not figured out a way to do this in a way that will result in halving these amounts.

My current dictionary outputs as such:

```
{'Water': '$0.00', 'Electric': '$42.78', 'Gas': '$272.65'}
```

At the end of the website scraping I was thinking to grab these keys and divide them by a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'Water': '2', 'Electric': '2', 'Gas': '2'}
```

Before I do so, I have to pass the first dictionary as `float` values.

Any ideas as to what the best way to do this is after having the dictionary established?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chop off the first character to remove the dollar sign, and then transform the sliced string into a float:

```py
data = {'Water': '$0.00', 'Electric': '$42.78', 'Gas': '$272.65'}
divisors = {'Water': '2', 'Electric': '2', 'Gas': '2'}
result = {key: float(value[1:]) / float(divisors[key]) for key, value in data.items()}

print(result) # Prints {'Water': 0.0, 'Electric': 21.39, 'Gas': 136.325}
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like there is a value in there that is passing through as a string into the dictionary. I'm trying to pinpoint which one it is currently. Once I figure out which one is the string, how would I go about passing a string `$45.65` as a float into the dictionary?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you clairfy what you mean by "passing through as a string"?

Comment: I might not be using the right vocab.
I am getting `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''` in the terminal after kicking off the script. I believe that one of the values of the dictionary is being interpreted as a string before being added to the dictionary. I might be thinking about this incorrectly. Relatively new to Python and webscraping!

Comment: I'm sorry I think I figured it out. One of the values is just returning blank which can obviously NOT be changed to a float. I'll run it again with a value and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Oh, you have an empty string in your input. In that case, use `result = {key: float(value[1:]) / float(divisors[key]) if len(value) > 0 else 0 for key, value in data.items()}`.

Comment: This will set the value of the key to `0` if you encounter the empty string.

Comment: Got you. I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: No problem! Have a great evening. :)